# save settings in Gitlab pipelines Run pipeline

Tags: python, git, gitlab, version-control

I have a Gitlab project and would like to run a pipeline with `Build > Pipelines > Run pipelines`. How to save the settings I make here, so I dont always have to make the variables again?

Also, when you run a pipeline from here, and theres a job in my project that should run when triggered, why doesnt it run?

```
job-name:
   ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
      when: always
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, when you run a pipeline from here, and theres a job in my project that should run when triggered, why doesnt it run?

You have to add another rule here. It should be "web":

```
job-name:
   ...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
      when: always
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
      when: always
```